# Computer stuck in a bootloop

Tags: windows-7, desktop-computer

recently I forced restart my pc, and all of a sudden, it won't start properly. The boot shows and I can enter cmos settings. But when booting it will restart itself after the logo. I can use my bootable usb, but windows detects no issue on hardware and software. I have tried unplugging and holding power button for 30 seconds, it still doesn't work. Is there anything i can do? Thanks!

Comment: Try steps in thread [my computer is stuck in a boot loop!](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/my-computer-is-stuck-in-a-boot-loop/a01b0273-6015-4638-b0ab-c0453d76dff3)

Comment: I will try to reset my os with recovery tools on windows recovery i suppose